# How am I able to individually select these 4 identical elements in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, selector

I am trying to extract each individual element that are exactly the same (there are 4 total of these. Here is the element:

```
<a href="#" ng-if="d.AvailableStatus != 'UNKNOWN'" ng-click="openDialog2('popuptempl1','/ImportAvailability/GetContainerInfoByContainerNumber',{Container_Nbr:d.WLContainerNumber, Terminal_Cd:d.TerminalCode},'Container Details')" class="ng-binding ng-scope">TCLUZZZZ004</a>
```

The problem is I do not know how to select one. None of them have a unique ID. They all share the same class names. Only the href text is unique which is 'TCLUZZZZ004' but I don't think its possible to select that in an  element to work with as an object, is it?

Thank you.

Comment: Select by class and check their text

Comment: so something like this? document.getElementsByClassName('ng-binding ng-scope').text('TCLUZZZZ004') ?

Comment: No @Chris , this will set the text to 'TCLUZZZZ004'.

Comment: So  you want to select these 4 elements? If the text is fixed, you can could filter the `a` using them.

Answer (score 0):

If all `a` tags share the same class use the `getElementsByClassName` function which returns an array of all tags, then use the index to access each one of them, like this:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("shared-classname");
var firstLink = list[0];
```

Then manipulate it the way you like.